# Trace self.variable

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am trying to trace a variable:

```
    def callback(*args):
        print "variable changed!"
    self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
    self.entryVariable.trace("w", callback)
```

This works fine, but I want to actually print out the variable in `callback`:

```
    def callback(self.entryVariable):
        print "variable changed!"
        print self.entryVariable.get()
    self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
    self.entryVariable.trace("w", callback(self.entryVariable))
```

But, I get

```
def callback(self.entryVariable):
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made the classic mistake of not giving the `trace()` function a `function` object, but the return value of that function. You could use `lambda`, but you don't have to use any parameter at all, so just use

```
self.entryVariable.trace("w", self.callback)
```

You can mention any `self.xxx` attribute anywhere in your class, so your method becomes:

```
def callback(self, *args):
    print "variable changed!"
    print self.entryVariable.get()
```

Comment: Not *anywhere*. As long as `callback` is defined inside of a class instance method, then `self` should be available.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to define callback outside of the method with the `self.entryVariable.trace("w", self.callback)`? I would like to bind changes in the variable to an event..

Comment: By the way, `def callback(*args):`seems to work, but `def callback():` gives     `return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() takes no arguments (3 given)`

Comment: @user99889 fix'd. And I've already assumed your defining the method outside the other method, as your calling your methods like `self.callback`.